# Error go-swagger docs generation when use json.RawMessage

Tags: go, swagger

I have a go web application with swagger docs generation. Recently in my project was added new endpoint that uses following struct in POST & PUT requests:

```golang
Secret struct {
        // Secret unique key name.
        Name string `json:"name" example:"ACCESS_TOKEN"`

        // type: string
        // x-go-type: "string"
        Value json.RawMessage `json:"value" swagger:"type:string"`

        // Tags in which this secret is used.
        Tags []string `json:"tags" example:"dev,prod,omitempty"`
    }
```

when i am attempt to build swagger docs with command: `swag init -md ./documentation -o ./swagger`
i am getting following error:

[image]

If i am correctly understand there should be added `type definition explicitly`, but i don't understand how to define type correctly, all combination of commentaries does not work. This issue is related with `json.RawMessage` type (Value field) because if i replace this type with interface{} everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution for my issue, previously i have to omit usage `--parseDependency` because swagger doc generation hangs but if i simultaneously pass `--parseDepth` 1 my docs generates successfully, so a full cmd is:

```
swag init --parseDependency --parseInternal --parseDepth 1 -md ./documentation -o ./swagger
```

As i understand this occurs because `json.RawMessage` **requires import** but if i am not using `--parseDependency` json.RawMessage type could not be found but in my question case single --parseDependency hangs so it could not be used. Solution is to use `--parseDepth` argument

Answer (score 0):

I was also using `swag init` when I generate swagger docs and found type `json.RawMessage` cannot find its type definition.
My cmd is like this:

```
swag init --parseDependency -g ./main.go
```

If I just add `--parseDepth 1` to my cmd (like the answer above).  It'll still be the same error.
As I add `--parseInternal` to my cmd. It finally succeed. Because If you want to parse types defined in internal packages, you will need to use `--parseInternal` in your cmd. So the complete cmd is like this:

```
 swag init --parseDependency --parseInternal -g ./main.go
```

Comment: In this way, type `json.RawMessage` would be parsed into array of integers